# how to grab data for the current date - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, elasticsearch, python-3.6, python-datetime

Below is my code that is grabbing data and converting the data into a CSV file (this is working). I am trying to only focus on the data that is returned for the current date.

Could someone show me how this is done please, DTDT is the date.
My Code:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
import csv

es = Elasticsearch(["9200"])

# Replace the following Query with your own Elastic Search Query
res = es.search(index="search", body=
                {
                    "_source": ["DTDT", "TRDT", "SPLE", "RPLE"],
                    "query": {
                        "bool": {
                            "should": [
                                {"wildcard": {"CN": "TEST*"}}

                            ]
                        }
                    }
}, size=10)



header_names = { 'DTDT': 'DATE', 'TRDT': 'TIME', ...}

with open('mycsvfile.csv', 'w') as f:  # Just use 'w' mode in 3.x
    header_present  = False
    for doc in res['hits']['hits']:
        my_dict = doc['_source'] 
        if not header_present:
            w = csv.DictWriter(f, my_dict.keys())
            w.writerow(header_names)  # will write DATE, TIME, ... in correct place
            header_present = True


        w.writerow(my_dict)
```

For example, I want to only return the data from midnight till 2pm (using the current date).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a range filter:

```
{
  "_source": [
    "DTDT",
    "TRDT",
    "SPLE",
    "RPLE"
  ],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "CN": "TEST*"
          }
        }
      ],
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "DTDT": {
              "gte": "now/d",
              "lte": "now+1d/d"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

*Edited to range on current calendar day with rounding, rather than last 24 hours.

Comment: Hi Mike, it is now only grabbing data for the current date which is good however, the wildcard is not working anymore. it is grabbing all the users not just the users that have test in their name.